# How to make something animate repeatedly

Tags: python

I am attempting to port the Double Dragon Arcade game over to python, but I am running into trouble when attempting to animate punching. The punch animation works when I press the punch key (j). I tried to make it so that .5 seconds after punching, the sprite changes back to regular form. I used the sleep command, but that just freezes the sprite for .5 seconds. My goal is to make it so that you can punch consecutively and after .5 seconds, the sprite changes back from the punch animation to the standing animation.

Below is the code for what I was attempting.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
class BillyLee(games.Sprite):
    image = games.load_image("billyleestill.bmp")
    image2 = games.load_image("billyleestilla.bmp")
    image3 = games.load_image("billypunchr.bmp")
    image4 = games.load_image("billypunchl.bmp")
    punchnumber = 0
    def __init__(self):
        super(BillyLee, self).__init__(image = BillyLee.image,
                                  x = 200,
                                  bottom = 400)    
    def update(self):
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_a):
            super(BillyLee, self).__init__(image = BillyLee.image2,
                                           x = self.x,
                                           bottom = self.bottom)
            self.x = self.x - 2
            BillyLee.punchnumber = 1
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_d):
            super(BillyLee, self).__init__(image = BillyLee.image,
                                           x = self.x,
                                           bottom = self.bottom) 
            self.x = self.x + 2
            BillyLee.punchnumber = 0
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_w):
            self.y = self.y - 2
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_s):
            self.y = self.y + 2
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_j) and BillyLee.punchnumber == 1:
            super(BillyLee, self).__init__(image = BillyLee.image4,
                                           x = self.x,
                                           bottom = self.bottom)
            #time.sleep(.5)
            super(BillyLee, self).__init__(image = BillyLee.image2,
                                           x = self.x,
                                           bottom = self.bottom)
        if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_j) and BillyLee.punchnumber == 0:
            super(BillyLee, self).__init__(image = BillyLee.image3,
                                           x = self.x,
                                           bottom = self.bottom)




        if self.y > 390:
            self.y = 390
        if self.y < 300:
            self.y = 300
        if self.x < 30:
            self.x = 30
```

Comment: What graphical library are you using? `animationStart = time()` and then `if time() - animationStart > 0.5: resetImage()`. Or use a timer/tick.

Comment: I have no idea.  My teacher didn't teach out of a book, and nearly every python example I see online has something he didn't teach us.

Comment: Then you're not porting a game, you're doing a school assignment. We need all of your code or at least your main loop in order to help you here. Also if you do not know what library you're using how the hell are we supposed to help you? I'm guessing Pyglet but that's a WILD assumption since most libraries have `Sprite`...

Comment: This isn't a school assignment.  I'm doing this for fun.  Also, this is all in pygame and python.